# Nginx config for symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I want to configure my symfony 2 application so that all `/web/app.php` are omited, unless that's `/web/app_dev.php`, then I want to enter the development environment.

The problem is that I always get 502 bad gateway error. What's wrong?

This is my current configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    # Server name being used (exact name, wildcards or regular expression)
    server_name domain.com;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    # Document root, make sure this points to your Symfony2 /web directory
    root /var/www/domain.com/web;

    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    # Logging
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.access.log;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your rewrite options might be colliding. You shouldn't need to define "app.php" three times. I've always just used `try_files   $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;` and skipped the `rewrite` commands.

Comment: Why not use the setup provided in the docs? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx